# Is there a way to find out if a wav file is uncompressed pcm or not?

Tags: python, audio

I'm currently programming a game with an engine that uses python as a base. Now I've stumbled upon the problem that I'm trying to play .wav files. As it does not work I looked into the routines there and found that it can only play uncompressed .wav files.

Now my question is is (as I didn't find anything there on how to see it) there any way to see if a .wav file is compressed or uncompressed?
(currently it is only a guess that it is compressed but can't make sure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the file header, byte 20-22 (PCM): Values other than 1 indicate some form of compression. (details here: http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/).